# mcrypt not loading in terminal

Tags: 14.04, php

I have installed mcrypt by following commands in ubuntu 14.04

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt

$ sudo php5enmod mcrypt

$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Now when I look into phpinfo its showing mcrypt is enable but when I look into terminal with `php -m` [PHP Modules] then it doesnt shows mcrypt there.

How to resolve above issue ?

Comment: Please try with `sudo apt install php-mcrypt`, I think with this package some dependencies will be installed. For more information: `sudo apt show php-mcrypt`.